# On a no ball, can both batsmen carry the stumps and run forever?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

When a bowler oversteps (or in rare cases, has the back foot touching the return crease) during the delivery stride, the umpire usually calls a no ball while the ball is still in play. On hearing this call, both batsmen could pluck out all three stumps at their end, and run with them to score runs for as long as they like!

From *Law 28 (The Wicket is down)* (quoted below), the fielding side won't be able to remake the wicket, so neither batsman can be run out. Without doubt, the batsmen doing this would be considered against spirit of the game, but is there anything in the Laws which prohibit it?

> #### 1. Wicket put down
>
> (a) The wicket is put down if a bail is completely removed from the
> top of the stumps, or a stump is struck out of the ground,
> ...
>
> The wicket is also put down if a fielder strikes or pulls a stump out
> of the ground in the same manner.
> ...
>
> #### 3. Remaking wicket
>
> If a wicket is broken or put down while the ball is in play, it shall
> not be remade by an umpire until the ball is dead. See Law 23 (Dead
> ball). Any fielder may, however, while the ball is in play,
>
> (i) replace a bail or bails on top of the stumps.
>
> (ii) put back one or more stumps into the ground where the wicket
> originally stood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a batsman carries the stumps deliberately, he is actually obstructing the field.

[Law 37 (Obstructing the field)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-37-obstructing-the-field/):

> #### 1. Out Obstructing the field
>
> Either batsman is out Obstructing the field if he **wilfully attempts to obstruct or distract the fielding side by word or *action***. In particular, but not solely, it shall be regarded as obstruction and either batsman will be out Obstructing the field if while **the ball is in play and after the striker has completed the act of playing the ball**.

So if he carry the stump after playing the ball he is obstructing the field.

[Law 24 (No ball)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/):

> #### 16. Out from a No ball
>
> When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any
>    of the Laws **except** 33 (Handled the ball), 34 (Hit the ball twice), **37
>    (Obstructing the field)** or 38 (Run out).

So as per the laws he will be given out.

Comment: This answer is right, but the second half of the first quote (starting "In particular..." is not relevant: the second half of that sentence, not included above, says (paraphrasing) "... if the batsman strikes the ball twice".